# Getting the time on a MySQL DB table entry

Tags: php, mysql, sql, database

I have a application form that should have been closed last friday. Due to things I can't control, it wasn't closed, and now people have applied after last friday. Unfortunately, those people can't come to the event, so we have to contact them to tell them the bad news.

My problem is, that when I made the form I was too fast and forgot to add a timestamp in the table.

Is there some way (either using php, phpmyadmin or sql-commands) to find out who has applied after a certain time (i.e. when the row was added to the table)?

The Database is a MySQL-database.

Comment: check apache access logs. I don't think any other way is left.

Comment: AFAIK: No, there isn't.

Comment: On database side your last chance would be an autoincrement column, if you have one.

Answer (score 1):

Does the table have an autoincrementing ID field?

If so, figure out the value of that ID field for the last person you were able to accept, then use this query in an SQL client like phpmyadmin.

```
  SELECT * 
    FROM tablename
   WHERE tablename.id > last_accepted_id
```

That will show all the rows for people to which you owe bad news.

Comment: The problem is that I don't know which one was the last accepted id, since all entries on friday should be accepted, but those on saturday and forward should not. I don't know which id was the last on friday.

Comment: What business rule made you want to stop accepting registrations?  Was the venue sold to capacity?  Knowing the capacity will let you know the last accepted person.  Is there some kind of midnight backup process for your database? If so you can restore a backup (NOT!! to your production database) and look at the highest id in the table.

Comment: We are having a dinner party and the place where we have the party does not accept additional applies later than a week before the party will be held, even though there may be capacity left.

This is not something we can change at the moment, and next time we may change the place to have a party. Our problem is that all places you can rent for parties in my town has the same rules.

Answer (score 0):

This may be possible if you have logging on (not on by default).

Your log file location is configured here in a .conf file.

```
/etc/*.conf
```

The logging will be written in that file as..

```
log=/tmp/yourlogfilename.log
```

If this is set you can go to that log and see when/what queries where used.